# Mysql query returns only the first letter of strings

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Can someone please tell me what I am missing. the following sql query returns only the first letter of strings it fetched from the my database:

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users) or die("error in the query");
```

thanks.

### Update

---

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                         FROM properties 
                         JOIN users USING(UserId) 
                        WHERE Level <> 'Admin' $pages->limit") or die("could not load all the properties"); 

$i=0; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
  $fn[$i] = $row ['FN']; 
  $ln[$i] = $row ['LN']; 
  $phone[$i] = $row ['Phone']; 
  $Email[$i] = $row ['Email']; 
}
```

...the part of the code that giving me head ache since yesterday. `$fn`, `$ln`, `$email and`$phone` all contain only one character. I think the error is on my own page but i just can't see it. anything concerning property contains the rite value

Comment: What does the "users" table look like? What data types are in its columns? And how are you determining that it's only showing the first character?

Comment: I'm assuming you have a closing " at the end of the sql query?  Can you show the code that you use to fetch the row data?

Comment: Please post the code where you read the result. I would guess that the error lies there.

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM properties JOIN users USING(UserId) WHERE Level<>'Admin' $pages->limit") or die("could not load all the properties");
$i=0;
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
$fn[$i] = $row ['FN'];
       $ln[$i] = $row ['LN'];
       $phone[$i] = $row ['Phone'];
       $Email[$i] = $row ['Email'];
}
the part of the code that giving me head ache since yesterdy. $fn, $ln and $email and $phone all contains only one character. I think the error is on my own page but i just can't see it. anything concerning property contains the rite value.thanks

Comment: this is weird, i just took off the [$i] to get something like this $fn, $ln, $email and $phone and i got the full information. Can someone explain to me what iam still missing. thanks a lot

Comment: You did not icrement $i in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the `while()` to allocate variables to an array, I don't think you need to use the `$i`, if you change the code to:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
  $fn[] = $row ['FN']; 
  $ln[] = $row ['LN']; 
  $phone[] = $row ['Phone']; 
  $Email[] = $row ['Email']; 
}
```

The `$row['whatever']` variable should be appended to the array. This was posted as an answer because it's too long to post as a comment (at least legibly); I don't, however, think it's affecting your problem.

It is, though, worth trying:

```
`echo "<pre>" . print_r(get_defined_vars(),true) . "</pre>";
```

to see what the contents of the variables are, and whether they're being returned from the db as one-character strings, or if it's happening in the code somewhere.

Comment: thanks a lot, i took off [$i] and it worked like a charm. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Either:

a. the fields in your database are declared with a one-character length, so that the data is actually being truncated

b. you're getting the right data, but something in the code displaying the data (which you haven't posted) is wrong, leading up to this result

Answer (score 1):

I can only presume that somewhere in the code previous to this you have set up `$ln`, `$ln`, `$phone` and `$Email` to some default string value. Then, because you aren't changing the value of $i from 0 in your loop you are setting the first letter of these strings to be equal to the string value returned from `mysql_fetch_array()` which has the effect of only changing the first letter. Difficult to explain so allow me to provide an example:

```
$tmp = 'A';
$tmp[0] = 'It does not matter how long this string is!';
echo $tmp;
```

The result of that snippet is that the single character "I" gets echoed.

Your code will work as:

```
$fn = $ln = $phone = $Email = array();
$i=0; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $fn[$i] = $row ['FN']; 
    $ln[$i] = $row ['LN']; 
    $phone[$i] = $row ['Phone']; 
    $Email[$i] = $row ['Email']; 
    ++$i;
}
```

Alternatively find where you have set the variables as strings.

Consider having an array of "user" objects because splitting up associated information like this is rarely useful.

e.g.

```
class User {
    public $first_name = '';
    public $last_name = '';
    public $phone_number = '';
    public $email = '';

    public function __construct($first, $last, $phone, $email) {
       $this->first_name = $first;
       $this->last_name = $last;
       $this->phone_number = $phone;
       $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function full_name() {
       return $first_name . ' ' . $last_name;
    }
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $users[] = new User($row['FN'], $row['LN'], $row['Phone'], $row['Email']);
}
```

Objects, IMHO, shouldn't have public properties but this is for example purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your foreach loop is incorrect. SQL looks good. Maybe you are doing something wrong later

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the array which is returned.
Add something like this:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

i had this similar problem once.... defining the arrays before assigning values to them helped me

try

```
$fn = array();
```

before going into the while loop

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem today. ( results only showing first letter of each variable ).

The situation was that my form data ( `$_GET` ) was using the same variable name as the array that was used later on after the query.

Once I changed the form data variable name, every thing was fine.

So, as a reminder to lazy people, when you paste old code into your page, double check variable names! :)